# WPF App crashing at startup - .NET Runtime Error Event Id 1026 in event viewer log

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, registry

I have a WPF application having .NET runtime 4.5.1. It runs fine on the development machine.

When I install on Windows 10 machine and try to launch the application it crashes then I checked Event Viewer logs I found a .net runtime error as follow:

```
Event ID : 1026
Source : .NET Runtime

Application: ABC.EXE
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Xml.XmlException
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.Exception)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.String, System.String[])
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[], Int32, Int32)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Configuration.XmlUtil..ctor(System.IO.Stream, System.String, 
Boolean, System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()

Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors
(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(System.String)

Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings()
at ABC.Application.Helpers.ResourceManager.get_DomainPath()
at ABC.Presentation.App..ctor()
at ABC.Presentation.App.Main()
```

Comment: Your `ABC.Application.Helpers.ResourceManager.DomainPath` property getter is throwing an unhandled exception.

Comment: At a guess, we'd need to see the code to go along with this. Would you edit it into the question please? You may have to be prompt about it, to help steer the question away from being closed (though it can be reopened again if it closes anyway).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Your app's configuration file contains at least one character that is invalid in the XML context.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and that there was an XML syntax error in the app.config, make sure you don't have any error in the config file which may lead to this issue.

In my case the issue was having a comment not closed correctly:

```
<!-- commented configuration /> <!-- another comment -->
```

The first comment wasn't closed properly, used `Notepad++` `XML Tools` plugin to validate it and discovered the issue.